# DOCX to PDF conversion in Alfresco - size limitation

Tags: pdf, alfresco, transformation, docx

I have written a custom Alfresco scheduler to convert DOCX files to PDF. PS: Alfresco 5.2.3 Enterprise Edition
I have noticed that Alfresco's OOTB configuration allows only those DOCX files to be converted to PDF whose size is 768 KB. DOCX files above 768 KB are not converted to PDF and exception is thrown in logs.

To overcome this, I have tried setting the following property in alfresco-global to increase the limit to 5 MB.

```
 content.transformer.JodConverter.extensions.docx.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
```

But when I test by uploading a 1.5 MB DOCX file, the following exceptions are thrown in logs.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:77)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:153)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:100)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:153)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:100)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:153)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:100)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:153)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:100)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:153)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:100)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:153)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:100)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFCloneUtility.cloneForNewDocument(PDFCloneUtility.java:153)
```

Code used to transform documents to pdf:

```
   String mimeType = contentService.getReader(doc, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT).getMimetype().trim();
   ContentReader docReader = contentService.getReader(doc, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);

        String pdfName = nodeService.getProperty(doc, ContentModel.PROP_NAME).toString();

        String fileExtension = Files.getFileExtension(pdfName);

        pdfName = pdfName.replace(fileExtension, "pdf");

        String targetMimetype = "application/pdf";

        ContentWriter writer = contentService.getWriter(doc, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
        writer.setMimetype(targetMimetype); // new mimetype
        writer.setEncoding(docReader.getEncoding()); // original encoding
        nodeService.setProperty(doc,ContentModel.PROP_NAME,pdfName);

        // Try and transform the content using the supplied delegate
        ContentTransformer pdfTransformer = contentService.getTransformer(mimeType, MimetypeMap.MIMETYPE_PDF);

        pdfTransformer.transform(docReader, writer);
```

Also, I tried configuring OOTB rule on a folder to convert incoming files to PDF. So, the below property is already configured in alfresco-global.

```
content.transformer.JodConverter.extensions.docx.pdf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
```

And now when I upload a 1.5 MB DOCX file to that folder, the file is not able to upload. I get Failure:504 message.

Any idea what can be the issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ring Alfresco support? That's part of what you get for paying for the Enterprise version!

Comment: I highly doubt that *only* changing the size limit will cause this kind of error. People routinely change that max all of the time. Question about your Java code: Why are you trying to write the PDF back to the original node? Wouldn't it be better to create a new nodeRef and write to it?

Comment: Actually Jeff, our requirement is to convert the original file to PDF and replace the original one with PDF. That's the reason we are doing so

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the stack memory. For example: `-Xss4m`.

Comment: Are you posting this as an answer or is this just a comment? It doesn't seem to be an answer.